# I can not create a table component using material-react-table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-react-table

I want to create a table component using material-react-table but I don't know which data type I should use to define its props (such as columns and data). I will define the props in an interface structure.

I used the MRT_ColumnDef as column type and an array of objects as data type and I know that they are incorrect. The columns can be defined using useMemo, for example,

```
 useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef<Employee>[]>(
     //define columns data
 );
```

and the data can be represented as an array of objects.